# Is Excel Evolutionary Algorithm similar to DEoptim in R?

Tags: r, nonlinear-optimization, evolutionary-algorithm, excel-solver, deoptimization

I am trying to solve a minimization problem using `DEoptim` in R. Previously, I used Excel's Solver tool, particularly the Evolutionary Solver technique. But the results from `DEoptim` don't match and are found often provide answers close to the given upper bounds of the parameters.

**Problem Statement**
I define the problem by minimizing the squared difference as represented in function `$f(q_1,q_2,\alpha_1,\alpha_2)$`

The objective function:
`$$f(q_1,q_2,\alpha_1,\alpha_2)= \frac{1}{5}\sum\limits_{i = 1}^{5} (b_{i} - b_{mod_{i}})^2$$`

With bounds:

```
lower = c(1000, 1000, 0.8, 1.4)
upper = c(1e10, 1e35, 1.5, 15.0)
```

where,

```
$$b_{mod,i} = q_{1} \lambda_i^{-\alpha_1} + q_{2} \lambda_i^{-\alpha_2}$$
```

and `$\lambda_i = c(375, 470, 528, 625, 880)$` are the wavelengths of 5 channels and
`$b_i = c(228,124,98,67,44)$` represents the light absorption measurement corresponding to each wavelength.

Here `$b_i$` is a measured value from a device and `$b_{mod,i}$` is the modelled value achieved by the optimization process.

**Queries**

I am trying to use this technique in R to solve a physical problem.

- Is `DEoptim` a good choice for the defined problem?
- Any suggestions on solving this problem using R?
- Are there any other optimization techniques to solve the present problem?

**Approach 1: Excel Solver**

In the Excel solver, I used the non-linear solver function with the inbuilt "Evolutionary" algorithm. The optimized values $q_1,\alpha_1,q_2,\alpha_2$ seems reasonable.

**Approach 2: in R using `DEoptim`**

I found that the Evolutionary algorithm in Excel is based on the Differential Evolutionary algorithm and in R there is a package called `DEoptim` ([Link](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DEoptim/DEoptim.pdf)). Also, I need to run the optimization process for a large data set where each timestamp of data represents $b$. However, `DEoptim` results were found to be very close to the upper bound and often are very sensitive to the bounds provided.

```
## Values:
b = c(858.3302, 523.2456, 429.2651, 310.0678, 222.0470)

## Define Objective Function
obj_fun = function(x){
            return(0.2*((b[1] - (x[1]*(375^(-x[2])) + x[3]*(375^(-x[4]))))^2 +
                  (b[2] - (x[1]*(470^(-x[2])) + x[3]*(470^(-x[4]))))^2 +
                  (b[3] - (x[1]*(528^(-x[2])) + x[3]*(528^(-x[4]))))^2 +
                  (b[4] - (x[1]*(625^(-x[2])) + x[3]*(625^(-x[4]))))^2 +
                  (b[5] - (x[1]*(880^(-x[2])) + x[3]*(880^(-x[4]))))^2))
  }

## Define Bounds
lower = c(1000, 1.5, 1000, 0.8)
upper = c(1e35, 15.0, 1e10, 1.4)

## Control Params
control.param = DEoptim.control(list(trace=0, parallelType = "parallel"))

## Run DEoptim
result = DEoptim(obj_fun, lower, upper, control.param)

## See Result

result$optim$bestmem

        par1         par2         par3         par4 
4.677653e+34 1.133396e+01 2.119513e+09 1.382064e+00
```

Excel Solver Result:
par1         par2         par3         par4
1.782904e+27    9.5913123   144797.964 0.9558152715

Comment: I don't have time on hand to go through your formula, so I'm afraid this is not a very tailored comment, but try setting a higher `itermax` in your DEoptim controls. Also, make sure your formula is set up such that a lower return is a 'success' - DEoptim minimises rather than maximises.